# What tool can write arbitrary mii register

Tags: ethtool

I did not see this capability in ethtool. Provided my driver support the  SIOCSMIIREG ioctl, I should be able to write any mii register. Do you know any tool that would make use of this capability ?

Answer (score 1):

Will 'mii-tool' not do what you need?

Comment: According to the man page, no.